# Connection reset by peer when calling .net web service from android

Tags: android

I developed a simple android application that calls a .net web service using ksoap2-android library version 2.6.0 . The problem is that it sometimes throws "Connection reset by peer" exception. I can't figure out the cause of this problem since it appears when using 3G network.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Reem Al-Hanbali

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be interrupted connection, mobile connections can be unstable. I would go with implementing graceful error handling and seeing if that helps.